# Building Concrete patio against the house with sunken family room for proper drainage

Tags: concrete, drainage, patio, grading

Just acquired this house with challenging problems. 
When the house was built, the builder didn't care for grading the lot appropriately. One of the rooms in the back of the house is below grade and it floods when it rains. The previous owner installed a sump pump in the backyard (green drum close to 2nd stake) to drain but it is clogged up with dirt.
The concrete patio is also incorrectly installed covering the stucco siding in part of the house. The circled location points to where there is 6" level difference between rooms.
I am thinking of re-grading the backyard part of the lot to divert water away from the property and digging a trench on one side of the house and run solid pipe french drain in it. 
Secondly, how to slope the (12'x41') patio from one end to the other while addressing the drop in floor level of 6" inside the house?

Seeking expert advice on the best way to handle the rear of the lot grading and sloping of the slab.

Note:
The first stake point on the side image with round pavers is 18" higher than the street, the second 19" but both are higher than the floor of the room the right side.

[image: Rear view][image: Left Half][image: Step Down][image: Right Half][image: Drain side]
[image]

Comment: You don't have a lot of exposed earth to absorb the run off from the home. If you have a higher grade at the house than the street level I would be installing a French drain from the back of the home to the front. That's a large slab to demo and replace if improved natural drainage can solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the sane advice. I'll read up more on French drains and find a knowledgeable pro in my area to do the regrading and drain install, leaving the concrete patio as is. The one room marked in blue in the layout sketch is at the same level as the patio.  I'll appreciate design guidance for the French darin.

Comment: If you plan to regrade the backyard, what were your plans for the trees and fence? Do you have a plot of survey for this house? Or plans to have it surveyed? Wondering where the water settles to currently. Is the current patio sloped for run off?  I graded my yard and installed a corrugated french drain over the summer. It was ALOT of work.

Comment: I have updated the layout sketch with level points A,B,C,D,E,F,G indicating results of level survey. Apparently, when the original patio was built, the soil dug up was simply moved to the backyard. There are plants/trees in a 3ft wide strip around the backyard perimeter. This area is even higher than the backyard.

Comment: Water currently settles just to the left of the chimney. Thinking of trenching between points A-F, installing 9" catch basins near E and D and laying 90' solid 4" PVC pipe in the trench ending in a pop-up emitter near the curb, sloping 15" total. Adequate drainage will prevent water accumulation. Solid PVC pipe should allow us to clean it if it ever gets clogged.